# How index is helping in this scenario is mongo db?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a collection with this structure,

> student_id,score,score_type

I have an index on score, and I want to query score of student with id=10000 and order the results by score.

I ran the query on my dataset and this is what the query plan is,

> 1: First the db uses the index on score to sort the documents.
>   2: Then it does the filter on the document with id:1000

Even though we use an index here, all the docs are examined here for the match(since there is no index on student_id). My question is that if all the documents are to be examined,why doesn't the db consider this alternate plan

> 1: Do a collection wide search and do the filtering.
>   2: Then use the index on score to do the sorting.

Here sorting will be done on a smaller dataset, so it should be faster.

What is wrong with the second plan?

Comment: Oddly enough, even having a separate index on `student_id` doesn't help it do filtering first. I can't explain it. Use the compound index suggested by @Markus

Answer (score 1):

Only one index can be used per query.

So if you want to query for a key and sort for another, you need a multi key index:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({student_id:1,score:1})
db.collection.find({student_id: 1000}).sort({score:1})
```

Comment: Isn't index intersection a thing for quite a time now?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Not with sort. ["MongoDB cannot use index intersection for the following query with sort: db.orders.find( { qty: { $gt: 10 } } ).sort( { status: 1 } )"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection-and-sort). However, feel free to edit.